# ArmCharts makechart with click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new here so bear with the question that I'm going to ask.

I want to create a click event for armcharts piechart. For example, when a user click the pie chart, it will open a new popup window.

My Code is as follow

```
chart = AmCharts.makeChart("piechart-placeholder2", {
    "type": "pie",  
"fontSize": 9.5,
"labelText": "[[percents]]%",
"theme": "light",
"legend": {
        "markerType": "circle",
        "position": "right",
    "marginRight": 80,      
    "autoMargins": false
    },
    "dataProvider": [{
        "Perkara": "xxx1",
        "Amaun(RM)": 4444
    }, {
        "Perkara": "xxx2",
        "Amaun(RM)": 5555
    }, {
        "Perkara": "xxx3",
        "Amaun(RM)": 73344
    }, {
        "Perkara": "xxx4",
        "Amaun(RM)": 3322
    }, {
        "Perkara": "xxx5",
        "Amaun(RM)": 56544
    }],
    "valueField": "Amaun(RM)",
    "titleField": "Perkara",
"balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>RM [[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
"exportConfig": {
    "menuTop":"0px",
    "menuItems": [{
        "icon": 'assets/img/export.png',
        "format": 'png'
    }]
}   
});
```

I know the `addListener` method, but I don't know how to apply it here.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listener to AmChart like this.

```
// add click listener
chart.addListener("clickItem", handleClick);
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts2/cV8GG/)

Comment: Take a look at the JSFiddle I posted, it should work. If your can't get it to work, create a jsfiddle for your code and I will take a look at it for you. @user3554311